# how to accept only apk file in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from "react";
export default function DropDown() {
  const changeHandler=()=>{
    let value=document.getElementById('someId');
    let ext = value.match(/\.([^\.]+)$/)[1];
    switch (ext) {
      case 'apk':
        alert('Allowed');
        break;
      default:
        alert('Not allowed');
        value = '';
    }
  };
return (
    <>
     <input type="file" id="someId" accept=".apk" onChange={changeHandler} />
    </>
  );
}
```

after selecting file it throws error value.match is not a function. how to resolve that if we click upload button if we upload apk file popup throws allow or else popup is not allowed

Comment: Your explanation is poor that we couldn't understand what you are trying to infer.Could you please explain properly

Comment: i want to upload apk file only by clicking the file upload button,if i want to upload except apk file in popup box it throws not allowed.if i want to create in code base runtime compiler throws error that"value.match is not a function".so my question is how to resolve this errors?

Comment: Instead of calling a function on input change, you can set the input value on a state and can handle the submit process after clicking a button

Comment: ok thanks .can you please give the idea in code base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `accept=".apk"` prop in the first place if it is supported by the browser would not allow non `.apk` files.

If you really want to get the actual filename with the extension, the event handler itself passes an event object. You just need to access the target of that event in your change handler.

```
const changeHandler=(e)=>{
  const filename = e.target.files[0].name; // filename.apk
  // do whatever you want.
}
```

you may also use `e.target.files[0].type` will also show what filename type was chosen.